# When Trying to access Elastic Search get using java getting Empty Response

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

Following the Docs of Elastic Search Was able to Set up the Java Environment for its API's.
But when Trying to access from an index called twitter, under a type called tweet, with id valued 1 the response is coming null with no error in console.

Code for the Above

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();

        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

        GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("twitter", "tweet", "2").get();
        System.out.println(response.getFields());

        client.close();
```

Kibana Console data for the Same

```
{
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "tweet",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "user": "Rahul",
          "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
          "message": "trying out Elasticsearch"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "tweet",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "user": "kimchy",
          "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
          "message": "trying out Elasticsearch"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you add a link to prepare Get function?

Comment: curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/0?pretty'

Comment: @Lax the data is comming fine in kibana console only when i try and access it through java it fails, even checked the cluster name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try some thing like this hope it helps

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")).build();

        Response response = restClient.performRequest("GET", "/twitter/_search",
               Collections.singletonMap("pretty", "true"));


/*
        JsonObject user = new JsonObject();
        user.addProperty("user","Yash");
        user.addProperty("post_date","2009-11-15T14:12:12");
        user.addProperty("message","Checking json");

        HttpEntity entity = new NStringEntity(user.toString());

        Response indexResponse = restClient.performRequest(
                "PUT",
                "/twitter/tweet/3",
                Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
                entity);
*/





        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

        restClient.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using HTTP , not HTTPs - the server may be hanging-up on you if you make a simple plain-text HTTP request?